# Error - Method assertEquals(Object, object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, Void)

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, assert

I have the following problem: I created a class that gets the text returned from the element. 
However, when making an assert in another test class, I get the following error:

```
Method assertEquals(Object, object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, Void)
```

Page with my getText:

```
public class access {
public statis void mensage() {
getDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//test.xxxx")).getText();
}}
```

Page with my test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
Assert.assertEquals("test", pageTwo.acess());
}
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: pageTwo.acess() is defined as returning void. Like ... public void access() { ... }

Comment: Have you defined a method named `acess()`? Your example just shows a class with the same name.